# Фильтрация $_SERVER

Tags: php

Фильтрует ли *PHP* такие параметры, как `$_SERVER`?

Например, если кто-то передаст `user-agent` длиной в 100500 символов :)

И стоит ли мне переживать, что такие параметры как `"user-agent" || "accept-language"` будут отсутствовать?

Comment: Скорее нет, чем да, есть общий максимальный вес запроса. Строка в 100кб для языка вполне подъемная вещь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Максимальная длина головной (head) части http запросов различна для разных веб-серверов.

- Для Apache по-умолчанию выставлено значение 8кб [Директива LimitRequestFieldSize](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize).
- IIS 4.0 - 2 МБ
- IIS 5.0 - 128 KB
- IIS 5.0 with Windows 2000 Service Pack 4 - 16 KB

  > [Про IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/260694)
- nginx - 8 KB [Директива large_client_header_buffers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#large_client_header_buffers)

Это длина всех заголовков в сумме, если размер превышен, то сервер должен отдать ошибку **413**.

Переживать наверно стоит из этого списка только за IIS 4.0.